# How to implement regular expression NFA with character ranges?

Tags: regex, dfa, nfa

When you read such posts as [Regex: NFA and Thompson's algorithm](http://blog.drennuz.com/regex-nfa-and-thompsons-algorithm/) everything looks rather straightforward until you realize in real life you need not only direct characters like "7" or "b", but also:

```
[A-Z]
[^_]
.
```

namely character classes (or ranges). And thus my question -- how to build NFA using character ranges? Using meta-characters like "not A", "anything else" and then computing overlapping ranges? This would lead to using tree-like structure when using final automaton, instead of just a table.

**Update:** please assume non-trivial in size (>>256) alphabet.

*I am asking about NFA, but later I would like to convert NFA to DFA as well.*

Comment: Would you clarify your mean of "build NFA using character ranges"

Comment: @revo, label the edge by `<a,k>` meaning using this label if input is `j` but not if input is `z`. This is not that hard but having several overlapping such labels (`<a,k>`, `h`, `<,>`) can cause a mess. And I am not a fan of reinventing the wheel, thus I am asking.

Comment: It's all in how you represent the edges. For an 8-bit character set, consider a bitmap of 256 bits. If bit *n* is set then character code *n* is in the allowed set, for example.

Comment: @tripleee, thank you. I think 8-bit in practice won't fly anymore, Unicode is more likely. But this would mean 8 KB per label (!). Is this approach used in any publicly known program, or is it just theoretical idea?

Comment: If you really need to support Unicode, there is a range of other considerations to take into account. See [UTS-18](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/) on regex support. In the meantime, maybe only consider supporting UTF-8 in a sensible way for a start.

Comment: The way I did this for my compilers classwhen I was in school was the following:Create States 1 and 2. For each character that allows for transition from State 1 to state 2, create a transition object that holds (State1, State2, char). This definitely doesn't help with variably large ranges though :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest approach would be:

1. Use segments as labels for transitions in both NFA and DFA. For example, range [a-z] would be reperesented as segment `[97, 122]`; single character 'a' would become `[97,97]`; and any character '.' would become `[minCode, maxCode]`.
2. Each negated range [^a-z] would result in two transitions from starting state to next state. In this example two transitions `[minCode, 96]` and `[123, maxCode]` should be created.
3. When range is represented by enumerating all possible characters [abcz], either transition per character should be created, or the code migh first group characters into ranges to optimize the number of transitions. So the [abcz] would become `[a-c]|z`. Thus two transitions instead of four.

This should be enough for NFA. However the classical [power set construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to transform NFA to DFA will not work when there are transitions with intersecting character ranges.
To solve this issue only one additional generalization step is required. Once a set of all input symbols created, in our case it will be a set of segments, it should be transformed into a set of non-intersecting segments. This can be done in time *O(n*Log(n))*, where n is a number of segments in a set using priority equeue (PQ) in which segments are ordered by the left component. Example:

```
  Procedure DISJOIN:
   Input  <- [97, 99] [97, 100] [98, 108]
   Output -> [97, 97] [98, 99], [100, 100], [101, 108]
```

**Step 2.** To create new transitions from a "set state" the algorithm should be modified as following:

```
   for each symbol in DISJOIN(input symbols)
     S <- empty set of symbols
     T <- empty "set state"
     for each state in "set state"
      for each transition in state.transitions
        I <- intersection(symbol, transition.label) 
        if (I is not empty)
        {
           Add I to the set S
           Add transition.To to the T
        }       

     for each segement from DISJOIN(S)
        Create transition from "set state" to T
```

To speed up matching when searching for a transition and input symbol C, transitions per state might be sorted by segments and binary search applied.