# Python locate specific words without duplicates

Tags: python

I have a problem. I am trying to find device names in a string. All the device names that I am looking for are stored in a List. There is one thing very important in what I want:

- **A command can have multiple devices!!!**

Now the problem I have is this:

I have two devices (`Fan` and `Fan Light`). When I give the command: `Turn on Fan Light` both devices have been found, but I want only `Fan Light` to be found. I tried checking all the devices that have been found and set the longest one as found device like this:

```
# Create 2 dummy devices
device1 = {
    "name": "fan"
}

device2 = {
    "name": "fan light"
}


# Add devices to list
devices = []
devices.append(device1)
devices.append(device2)


# Given command
command = "Turn on fan light"
    
    
foundDevices = []

# Search devices in sentence
for device in devices:

    # Splits a device name if it has multiple words
    deviceSplit = device["name"].split()
    numOfSubNames = len(deviceSplit)

    # Checks for every sub-name if it is found in the string
    i = 0
    for subName in deviceSplit:
        if subName in command:
            i += 1

    # Checks if all names where located in string
    if i == numOfSubNames:
         foundDevices.append(device["name"])

# Checks if multiple devices have been found
if len(foundDevices) >= 2:
    largestNameLength = 0

    # Checks which device has the largest name
    for device in foundDevices:
        if (len(device) > largestNameLength):
            largestName = device
            largestNameLength = len(device)


    # Clears list and only add longest one
    foundDevices.clear()
    foundDevices.append(largestName)


print(foundDevices)
```

But that gives a problem when I say for example: "Turn on Fan Light and the Fan", because that command does contain multiple devices.
How can I scan for devices the way I want?

Comment: this is related to entity recoginzation, if you dont want to that way i suggest you to provide command after the fan word, like `fan run` or `fan stop`

Comment: so what would be the result from `"turn on the Fan Light, and also the fan"` (with different capitalization)?

Comment: Or you can identify all positions where a match occurs, e.g. using ```find``` and discard submatches, i.e. devices that are contained in a larger match.

Comment: The result of: `"Turn on the Fan Light and the Fan"` should be: `["Fan Light", "Fan"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression search is one way of quickly doing what you want, with a pattern made from the different device names.

```py
import re

def find_with_regex(command, pattern):
    return list(set(re.findall(pattern, command, re.IGNORECASE)))
```

I would also suggest building the reversed dictionary of `device: name` shape, maybe it would help quickly finding the code name of a given device.

```py
devices = [{'name': 'fan light'}, {'name': 'fan'}]

# build a quick-reference dict with device>name structure
transformed = {dev: name for x in devices for name, dev in x.items()}
# should also help weeding out duplicated devices
# as it would raise an error as soon as it fids one

# print(transformed)
# {'fan light': 'name', 'fan': 'name'}
```

Special thanks to [buddemat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14015737/buddemat) for pointing out that device names to be in a particular order for this solution to work, fixed it with `reversed(sorted(...` on the pattern making line from the next code block.

Testing the function

```py
test_cases = [
    'Turn on fan light',
    'Turn on fan light and fan',
    'Turn on fan and fan light',
    'Turn on fan and fan',
]

pattern = '|'.join(reversed(sorted(transformed)))
for command in test_cases:
    matches = find_with_regex(command, pattern)
    print(matches)
```

Output

```
['fan light']
['fan', 'fan light']
['fan', 'fan light']
['fan']
```

Comment: you can remove the `IGNORECASE` flag if you don't need it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python `regex` module instead of the `re` module (to improve upon RichieV's nice answer), if you don't want to rely on sorting the list of devices to ensure the correct result.

The problem with `re` is, is that it is not POSIX compliant and thus, the pipe operator `|` will not ensure that the *longest leftmost* match is returned (see also [How to order regular expression alternatives to get longest match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997376/how-to-order-regular-expression-alternatives-to-get-longest-match)).

However, in `regex` you can specify `(?p)` before a regex pattern to ensure POSIX matching.

Altogether

```
import regex

devices = [{'name': 'fan'}, {'name': 'fan light'}]

test_cases = [
    'Turn on fan light',
    'Turn on fan light and fan',
    'Turn on fan and fan light',
    'Turn on fan and fan',
]

transformed = {dev: name for x in devices for name, dev in x.items()}

pattern = '|'.join(transformed)

for command in test_cases:
    matches = regex.findall(r'(?p)'+pattern,command)
    print(matches)
```

will give you

```
['fan light']
['fan light', 'fan']
['fan', 'fan light']
['fan', 'fan']
```

regardless of the order of the dictionaries in `devices`.